# Use callable function over onTrigger function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to update some data using batch updates. Firebase docs state that bulk updates should be performed server-side. Should I use a onTrigger or a callable function?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation that you're referring to?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions. In batch writes section it says:  For bulk data entry, use a server client library with parallelized individual writes. Batched writes perform better than serialized writes but not better than parallel writes. You should use a server client library for bulk data operations and not a mobile/web SDK.

Comment: My question might be confusing. I would like to know if there is any advantage in using onTrigger function over callable function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of performing writes to Firestore, it doesn't matter what kind of function you use.  It is going to run the same code with the same performance characteristics.